# How to localise CL applications in macOS (Xcode)?

Tags: swift, xcode, command-line, localization, command-line-interface

I am having trouble localising a command-line application I've created in Xcode. Here's what I did:

- Used `NSLocalizedString` on all strings to be translated
- Add base localisation, and the target localisation under Project settings
- Add Strings file, check both English, and target language checkboxes
- Create strings to be localised via `genstring` (both English and target language) and localised them as necessary

When I build the application, I still get all the text in English. What could be the issue here? My system is set to my target language, and when I try to add a scheme with the target language, I get the following error:

> Error: 2 unexpected arguments: '(language_code)', 'NO'

This error is only present if I use swift-argument-parser for the application. For plain applications, it's still not possible to get the localised version.

Xcode 11.3, macOS10.15.3

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you build a Cocoa application (with `NSApplicationMain`), the framework will take care of loading the appropriate localized strings from the main bundle.  The framework will [parse UserDefaults overrides from command line arguments](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1410665-argumentdomain), so you/Xcode can supply [locale settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH7-SW2) via flags like `-AppleLanguages` and `-AppleLocale` .

When you write a command-line utility, by default there is no bundle, no startup logic that performs localization, and no parsing of UserDefaults.  Setting the target language from the scheme just adds the arguments (which is why you get an error from `swift-argument-parser`).  However, you can load resources from a bundle yourself.

```swift
// Get the language from UserDefaults (to support scheme settings, will also need to parse command line arguments)
let language = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "AppleLanguages")?.first ?? "en"
// In addition to the command-line binary, you'll also need a bundle with the translations somewhere
let path = "/path/to/\(language).lproj"  
let lproj = Bundle(path: path)
let localized = lproj?.localizedStringForKey("key", value: nil, table: nil)
```

Note that `Bundle.main` for an unbundled command line utility will just be the parent directory of wherever the binary is.  So you can also use `NSLocalizedString` if your lproj files are built/installed in the appropriate place, but this would be unusual for utilities installed to binary directories like `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I came up with adding a function which gets the `Bundle.module.path` from the argument, with `ofType: "lproj"`, then passing it to the constant to use it with the `.module` argument. I think this does the same thing. Thank you for the answer!